# Spring and hibernate: No Session found for current thread

Tags: spring, hibernate, sessionfactory

im gettting the following error

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1024)
at com.fexco.shoptaxfreemobile.service.ProfileService.registerVisitor(ProfileService.java:57)
at com.fexco.shoptaxfreemobile.controller.ProfileController.registerVisitor(ProfileController.java:91)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.fexco.shoptaxfreemobile.jsonp.JsonpCallbackFilter.doFilter(JsonpCallbackFilter.java:33)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Service class

```
@Service
public class ProfileService {

    @Resource(name = "mySessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    private ProfileDao profileDao;

    private class CountrySorter implements Comparator<Country> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Country country1, Country country2) {
            if ( country1.getId().compareTo(new Long (3)) < 0){
                return country1.getId().compareTo(country2.getId());
            }
            return country1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(country2.getName());
        }               
    }

    public List<Country> getCountries() {

        List<VisitorCountry> visitorCountries = profileDao.getAllCountries();       

        List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<Country>();
        for ( VisitorCountry country : visitorCountries){
            countries.add(country.getCountry());
        }

        Comparator<Country> comparator = new CountrySorter();       
        Collections.sort(countries, comparator);

        return countries;
    }

    public RegisterResponse registerVisitor(JsonVisitor visitorDetails){
        Visitor storedVisitor = (Visitor) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Visitor.class, visitorDetails.getTfscNumber(), LockMode.NONE);
        if ( storedVisitor == null){
            storedVisitor = new Visitor(visitorDetails);
        }else{
            storedVisitor.setVisitorDetails(visitorDetails);    
        }

        try{
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(storedVisitor);

        }catch(Exception ex){
            return new RegisterResponse(false, "Failed To Register Card. Please Try Again Later.", visitorDetails);
        }

        return new RegisterResponse(true, "", visitorDetails);

    }
}
```

bit of DAO class

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ProfileDao {

    @Resource(name = "mySessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public List getAllCountries(){

        List<VisitorCountry> visitorCountries = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .getNamedQuery("GET_ALL_COUNTRIES").list();

        return visitorCountries;

    }

    public List<Retailer> getRetailerByRetailerNumber(String retailerNo) {

        List<Retailer> retailerByRetailerNumber = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .getNamedQuery("FindRetailerByRetailerNo").setString("retailerNo", retailerNo).list();

        return retailerByRetailerNumber;
    }
```

and i have this in my application-context.xml

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            <![CDATA[
        hibernate.show_sql=true
        hibernate.format_sql=true
        hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
        ]]>
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

can anyone spot why i am getting the following error?

Comment: jordan002's answer is correct, but the "real" problem is, that instead of calling DAO in your service, you are accessing DB from service class...

On the other hand typically you want service method to behave transactionally instead of just DAO methods - if you have 2 updates in service method and second one fails, transactions don't help you to have DB consistent (but it depends on your business logic).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You annotated your Dao class with @Transactional, but not your service class.  The line:

```
Visitor storedVisitor =
    (Visitor) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Visitor.class,
            visitorDetails.getTfscNumber(), LockMode.NONE);
```

requires you to be in a transaction.

You can fix this by adding the @Transactional annotation to your ProfileService class, or just the registerVisitor() method.

Comment: This goes further and helps with getting hibernate to write updates/deletes.

Answer (score 14):

I solved the same problem with following 2 steps

1. Placed `@Transactional` on the service method as suggested
   **jordan002** in his answer on this page.
2. One more thing,If you have 2 configuration files: say
   `application-context.xml`(For DB and Application Context Specific
   configuration) and `webmvc-context.xml`(For web/controller specific
   configuration), then you should scan the packages different for your
   controllers and dao.

   The `webmvc-context.xml` is loaded after `application-context.xml`.
   I think the DAO class is loaded first with transactional references
   when the application-context.xml is loaded, but it is replace with
   another object, without transactional references, when
   webmvc-context.xml is loaded.

   Any way, I resolve the problem with specific packages scanned:

   ```
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.app.repository" />
   ```

   for `application-context.xml`

   and

   ```
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.app.web" />
   ```

   for `webmvc-context.xml`.

Answer (score 6):

change your DAO 's annotation with @Repository

```
@Repository
public class ProfileDao { 
.
.
.
}
```

and then make your service method @Transactional for example like this

```
@Transactional
public List<Retailer> getRetailerByRetailerNumber(String retailerNo) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved the above problem by following two step

1-Adding @Transactional support in my service method which is calling DAO methods

2-By importing the applicationContext.xml in spring-servlet.xml in this way

```
 <import resource="applicationContext.xml" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.json.api.*" />
<!--Third Party Integration should be injected in xml start here -->
    <bean id="integrationInterface" class="com.json.api.IntegerationInterface"></bean>
<!--Third Party Integration should be injected in xml start here -->
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="apiServiceInterceptor" class="com.json.api.interceptor.ApiServiceInterceptor"></bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
<!--To Enable @Value to map key with provided fields for property files -->
<context:property-placeholder />
```

It removes the need to scan packages in two places spring-servlet.xml and applicationContext.xml

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an question with some age, but I ran into this issue and found that if you are using Spring-Java configuration, that a resolution had a couple parts to this. Relative placement of some configuration to the controller was important.

First, the CoreConfiguration

```
@Configuration
public class CoreConfiguration {
@Bean          
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    String annotatedPckgs[] ={"org.tigersndragons.reports.model.warehouse"};
    factoryBean.setAnnotatedPackages(annotatedPckgs);           
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    try {
        hibernateProperties.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("props/hibernate.properties"));        
        factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
    } catch (IOException e) { }
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("org.telligen.reports.model.warehouse");
    factoryBean.setDataSource(warehouseDataSource());//("jdbc/warehouse");
    try {
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (IOException e) {       }
    return factoryBean;
}
@Bean
public WarehouseDAO getWarehouseDAO(){
    WarehouseDAO wrhsDao = new WarehouseDAO();
    wrhsDao.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return wrhsDao;
}
```

...

```
@Configuration
public class ScheduleConfiguration {
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduleConfiguration.class);

@Autowired
private CoreConfiguration coreConfiguration;


@Bean
public HandlerMapping handlerMapping(){
    DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping mapping =  new DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping();
    mapping.setInterceptors(new Object []{coreConfiguration.openSessionViewInterceptor()});
    return mapping;
}

@Bean
public HandlerAdapter handerAdapter(){
    return new AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter();
}

@Bean
public ScheduleController scheduleController() throws Exception{
    ScheduleController controller = new ScheduleController();
        controller.setWrhsDao(coreConfiguration.getWarehouseDAO());
    return controller;
}

 ...
```

In the Controller, I had to set

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping
public class ScheduleController {
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduleController.class);

private WarehouseDAO wrhsDao;
    @RenderMapping
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public String viewSchedule(Map<String, Object> modelMap){...}

public void setWrhsDao(WarehouseDAO wrhsDao) {
    this.wrhsDao = wrhsDao;
}
}
```

The WarehouseDAO has the @Repository annotation and the SessionFactory was not Autowired.

Hope this helps someone else with similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just add something that took me some time to debug : don't forget that a @Transactional annotation will only work on "public" methods.

I put some @Transactional on "protected" ones and got this error.

Hope it helps :)

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

> **Method visibility and @Transactional**
>
> When using proxies, you should apply the @Transactional annotation
>   only to methods with public visibility. If you do annotate protected,
>   private or package-visible methods with the @Transactional annotation,
>   no error is raised, but the annotated method does not exhibit the
>   configured transactional settings. Consider the use of AspectJ (see
>   below) if you need to annotate non-public methods.