# Using JUnit to test my dao layer : Spring and hibernate with JavaConfig

Tags: spring, hibernate, junit

I'm working on a spring web application using hibernate and spring security.

After implementing the DAO (using generic dao pattern) and making a CustomUserDetailService for and CustomUserDetails for spring security, it seems I can't login (I was using in memory ids and it was working) so I thought that it must be a problem in my DAO.

1) I'm using JavaConfig for my configuration and this initializer :

```
public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class,SecurityConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

I've never used JUnit testing before, and all the examples I found use xml config so I need some help on that, an example would be great.

2) Since I couldn't use JUnit I tried to get an idea what the problem was so I added a controller method where I get some users and show them in a page, but my GlobalException Handler intercepted that and redirected me to the error page with this exception :

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: No Session found for current thread; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
```

Here's my GenericDaoImpl:

```
public class GenericDaoImpl<T,ID extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<T,ID> {


    private Class<T> persistentClass;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public GenericDaoImpl(Class<T> persistentClass) {
        this.persistentClass = persistentClass;
    }

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Session getSession()
    {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean create(T t) {

        if (t== null)  return false;
        getSession().saveOrUpdate(t);
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public T getById(ID id) {

         return (T) getSession().get(persistentClass,id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean update(T t) {

        if (t==null) return false;
        getSession().update(t);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete(T t) {

        if (t==null) return false;
        getSession().delete(t);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deleteById(ID id) {
        T t =getById(id);
        if (t==null) return false;
        getSession().delete(t);
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<T> findByOneCriteria(Criterion criterion) {
        Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(persistentClass);
        criteria.add(criterion);
        return (List<T>)criteria.list();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<T> findByCriterias(ArrayList<Criterion> criterions) {
        Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(persistentClass);
        for (Criterion c : criterions)
        criteria.add(c);
        return (List<T>)criteria.list();
    }
}
```

And my PersonnelDaoImpl:

```
@Repository
public class PersonnelDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<Personnel,Integer> implements PersonnelDao {

    public PersonnelDaoImpl(){
        super(Personnel.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Personnel findByUsername(String username) {
       List<Personnel> result = findByOneCriteria(Restrictions.like("username",username));
       return result.get(0);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Personnel> findByRole(int role) {
        return findByOneCriteria(Restrictions.eq("role",role));
    }
}
```

I don't get what's wrong.

Comment: Are you getting an exception when you try to login?

Comment: i solved the second part of the problem (i added an answer), and to answer your querstion :no, the exception i got is when i test my service ( i made a page that can be accessed even if the user is not logged in, and that uses the service used for the login) and i got the above exception

Answer (score 1):

Creating configuration for the test case using Java,

Use these annotations on your test class.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Config.class})
public class ServiceTest{

}
```

and the Config.class would look like,

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
}
```

Define the beans in the Config class and execute the test case.

2)
Its crystal clear that `No session` indicates that there is not `TransactionManager` defined in the layer that calls your DAL.

Try to use `@Transactional` which does that for you.

Note: Please make sure that `@Transactional` allows value attribute which is defaulted to `transactionManager`

Comment: 2) i figured that, and i added an answer , the problem now is with the unit test, it doesn't seem to work like you discribed above(i already tried it like ), doesn't it need the initializer too ? if yes, how to include it ?

Comment: Why do Unit test need Transaction manager when every thing should be mocked ? You mean Integration test ?

Comment: I'm using unit tests to check if my service are working correctly or not, or at least, i want to check if my repositories are working correctly or not, if there's another solution please be my guest ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the second part 2), i found the solution, i had to add `@Transactional` to my service, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298483/spring-and-hibernate-no-session-found-for-current-thread) post helped me