# Spring + Hibernate : No Session Found For Current Thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, authentication, spring-security

I'm having difficulties solving this problem:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:993)
    at com.veram.dao.UsuariosDaoImp.findByUserName(UsuariosDaoImp.java:23)
    at com.veram.servicos.ServicosUsuario.loadUserByUsername(ServicosUsuario.java:31)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:132)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
```

Classes:

AppConfig

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.ver.*"})
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class, DataBaseConfig.class })
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter 
{       
    //Adiciona a pasta resources ao dispatcher do MVC
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) 
    {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) 
    {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    //Localização das views da minha aplicação
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() 
    {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver 
                          = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }       
}
```

DataBaseConfig:

```
@Configuration
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })
public class DataBaseConfig 
{       
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() 
    {
            LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource());

            builder.scanPackages("com.ver.entid").addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
            return builder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() 
    {
        Properties prop = new Properties();

        prop.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        prop.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        prop.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        return prop;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public BasicDataSource dataSource() 
    {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
            ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/veram_prod");
        ds.setUsername("root");
        ds.setPassword("root");
        return ds;          
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager txManager() 
    {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
    }     
}
```

UserServices:

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class ServicosUsuario implements UserDetailsService 
{   
    @Autowired
    private UsuariosDao userDao;

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException 
    {           
        com.veram.entidades.Usuarios user = userDao.findByUserName(username);
    }
}
```

UserDaoImp

```
@Repository
public class UsuariosDaoImp implements UsuariosDao
{       
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Usuarios findByUserName(String username)
    {     
        List<Usuarios> users = new ArrayList<Usuarios>();

        users = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery("from usuarios where usuario=?")
            .setParameter(0, username)
            .list();

        if (users.size() > 0) 
        {
            return users.get(0);
        } 
        else 
        {
            return null;
        }     
    }    
}
```

I'm trying to understand the configuration for Spring and Hibernate. Every time I try to access the current session, I get a no session found for current thread error in my console (doesn't stop the app).
If anyone can help, I appreciate!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring and hibernate: No Session found for current thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298483/spring-and-hibernate-no-session-found-for-current-thread)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `@EnableTransactionManagement` to `DataBaseConfig`