# How can I replace HibernateTemplate and HibernateCallback in my Spring 4/Hibernate 4 project?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm working on a very large, old spring3, hibernate3 project, and am tasked with upgrading it to spring4 hibernate4.

Apparently HibernateTemplate is no longer supported in hibernate4, so when I upgrade, our client code breaks.

All of our DAOs extend the HibernateDaoSupport
Lots of the DAO code looks like this:

```
public class ManagerDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements ManagerDAO {

public List<Person> getManagers() {
    List l = (List) this.getHibernateTemplate().executeFind(new HibernateCallback(){
        public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
            List result = (List) session.createQuery(MySqlQueryString).list();
            return result;
        }
    });
    return l;
}

//........

}
```

it is wired up in XML like:

```
<bean id="managerDaoImpl" class="com.foo.bar.hibernate.ManagerDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="MySessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

and

```
<bean id="MySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource"     ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>
```

**What I thought I needed to do:**

```
public List<Person> getManagers() {}
            List result = (List) getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession.createQuery(MySqlQueryString).list();
            return result;
    return l;
}
```

but this gives me an error like:

```
Property 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
```

What am I doing wrong?

I thought the whole point of hibernateTemplate being deprecated is that Spring 3+ could handle the transactions for me?

I really didn't think a "path of least resistances" approach to upgrading such commonly used technologies would involve getting my hands dirty with the likes of sessions sessions and transaction scopes.

Answer (score 1):

As Taylor said, you need to have transactions configured.

Refer to below posts for more details:

1) [Spring and hibernate: No Session found for current thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298483/spring-and-hibernate-no-session-found-for-current-thread)

2) [Spring + Hibernate : No Session found for current thread](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-hibernate-no-session-found-for-current-thread/) where it says:

> The sessionFactory needs transaction to work, to solve it, declare a
>   transaction manager in Spring.

Answer (score 0):

(Once you configure everything...)
HibernateDaoSupport which is extended by your class, ManagerDaoImpl, has the protected method currentSession(). so you can just write

```
public List<Person> getManagers() {}
            List result = (List) currentSession.createQuery(MySqlQueryString).list();
            return result;
    return l;
}
```

Comment: That's some strange code with 2 returns... please check it again.

Answer (score -1):

Have you read through spring transaction management?

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

You can wire up a global txn interceptor and then just mark your business/service methods (DAO is probably too low level) with @Transactional.  LMK if you need details.  Cheers.

**EDIT:**
In response to Paul's comment (baking it into answer cause it's too long for comment).

@Transactional is meant to be used at a method level, but in my experience DAO is too low level.  To be clear, a single conceptual operation can involve multiple DAO-level operations, and the advantage of transactional boundary being at the business operation level rather than the DAO-level is that you get a more consistent state because otherwise parts of the business operation can fail but the others have already been committed.

Comment: "DAO is probably too low level" - what do you mean? I thought the hibernateCallback was the scope of the transaction previously? Would @transaction at a method level cause problems?

Comment: I expanded on this a bit in my answer.

Comment: Aaah, I get what you mean, thank you! :) My brain was just fried yesterday when I was trying to understand your answer. 
I have another question: The way the callbacks work in the old code - it's the callback that delimits the scope of the transaction, yes? so.... shouldn't I implement my new transactions programmatically (as opposed to via XML and an interceptor)  in my new code too?

Comment: You can, it's up to you, but the @Transactional + AOP is the conventional spring approach.

Comment: but the hibernateCallbacks actually are what delimits my transactions at the moment? That's what that method call does? 

Primary goal at this point is making the existing code work as before, so choosing the same pattern as before seems like a good route - what would I use if I wanted to replicate these 'programmatic sessions' in spring 4?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  The tempalte does the txn management.  To maintain your current txn boundaries, annotate the `getManagers` method with @Transactional.