# Autowiring sessionfactory inside thread run method not working

Tags: spring, multithreading, hibernate, autowired

I am trying to autowired hibernate session factory into the run method of thread. But it shows the following error

`Exception in thread "Timer-6" org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread`

my class is as follows

```
public class CroneJobNew extends TimerTask {
@autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory ; 


@Override
public void run() {
List<Shop>  shops = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Shop.class).list();
System.out.println("shops size"  + shops.size());

}


}
```

How can I slove this?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you are not using `@EnableAsync` and `@Async` annotatations for handling threads?? Autowiring with these annotations in place works like a charm..

Comment: I am using this thread for creating a timer. My class CroneJobNew  implements this thread class by default.

Comment: just see this answer,[Spring and hibernate: No Session found for current thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298483/spring-and-hibernate-no-session-found-for-current-thread),i think this would be help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace method getCurrentSession() to openSession() and also you need to add session.beginTransaction() (finally close it) because you are working without @Transactional scope

Comment: I am using multiple sessionFactory.openSession() in my run method.So when I close a session factory with sessionFactory.close(); it shows the following error                                                                            Exception in thread "Timer-0" org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your class is Annotated with `@Component` for spring dependency Injection.

[Refer this doc for Configuring Session Factory Bean](http://www.ekiras.com/2016/02/how-to-use-configure-session-factory-bean-springboot.html)

If you are working with spring-boot, you will have to manually configure `SessionFactory` Bean to get it working.